# Erlang Sort Function wanted

Tags: mongodb, sorting, erlang

I have following tuple

```
{{

'_id',{<<85,192,187,141,133,234,141,13,74,0,0,1>>},

mobile_no,<<"9930050224">>,

email,<<"prakhar@bwa.io">>,

name,<<"PT">>,

user_role,<<"broker">>,

user_id,<<"fp85od1zv5x4jddkens6648z5bc9jroj">>

}}
```

In form of =>

```
{{

key1, value1

key2, value2....

}}
```

Can a simple function call sort on basis of keys as under without parentheses?:

```
{{

'_id',{<<85,192,187,141,133,234,141,13,74,0,0,1>>},

email,<<"prakhar@bwa.io">>,

mobile_no,<<"9930050224">>,

name,<<"PT">>,

user_id,<<"fp85od1zv5x4jddkens6648z5bc9jroj">>,

user_role,<<"broker">>

}}
```

Can you define a simple function to sort the all parameters in {key, value} based on key parameters, but there are no parenthesis around each key, value

Comment: Why do you need them to be sorted to begin with? This is important to provide a practical answer.

Comment: Where you get so screwed up data? Why you don't have `{[{key1, val1}, {key2, val2}]}`? If you find an answer to this question or transform to this form you have solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I won't comment about why you need this function, though I agree with "@I GIVE TERRIBLE ADVICE" and @Hynek. Here is a solution to your question:

```
1> Ut = {{'_id',{<<85,192,187,141,133,234,141,13,74,0,0,1>>},mobile_no,
<<"9930050224">>,email,<<"prakhar@bwa.io">>,name,<<"PT">>,user_role,<<"broker">>,user_id,<<"fp85od1zv5x4jddkens6648z5bc9jroj">>}}.
{{'_id',{<<85,192,187,141,133,234,141,13,74,0,0,1>>},
    mobile_no,<<"9930050224">>,email,<<"prakhar@bwa.io">>,name,
    <<"PT">>,user_role,<<"broker">>,user_id,
    <<"fp85od1zv5x4jddkens6648z5bc9jroj">>}}
2> Group2 = fun Group2([],R) -> R; Group2([A,B|T],R) -> Group2(T,[{A,B}|R]) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.36.54118792>
3> Group = fun(L) -> Group2(L,[]) end.                                          
#Fun<erl_eval.6.54118792>
4> F = fun(In) -> {X} = In, list_to_tuple(lists:sort(Group(tuple_to_list(X)))) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.54118792>
5> F(Ut).
{{'_id',{<<85,192,187,141,133,234,141,13,74,0,0,1>>}},
 {email,<<"prakhar@bwa.io">>},
 {mobile_no,<<"9930050224">>},
 {name,<<"PT">>},
 {user_id,<<"fp85od1zv5x4jddkens6648z5bc9jroj">>},
 {user_role,<<"broker">>}}
6>
```

Comment: thnx. this worked well. Needed this for testing two different versions of mongodb.

Comment: Good, I understand now why you have no control on the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Shlok, you're fighting an uphill battle working directly with raw BSON tuples. Use the [BSON library API](https://github.com/comtihon/bson-erlang) to access the data that they contain:

```
2> RawDoc.
{'_id',{<<85,192,187,141,133,234,141,13,74,0,0,1>>},
       email,<<"xxxxyyyy@bwa.io">>,mobile_no,<<"0000022222">>,name,
       <<"PT">>,user_id,<<"fp85od1zv5x4jddkens6648z5bc9jroj">>,
       user_role,<<"broker">>}
3> bson:at(email, RawDoc).
<<"xxxxyyyy@bwa.io">>
5> Key = fun(Key, Doc) -> {Key, bson:at(Key, Doc} end.
7> {Key(user_id, RawDoc), Key(user_role,RawDoc)}.
{{user_id,<<"fp85od1zv5x4jddkens6648z5bc9jroj">>},
 {user_role,<<"broker">>}}
```

Ideally, you should write a function to convert there BSON tuples to the Erlang `#record{}` you're using to model your data, end of story.

If you assume you'll be getting BSON objects with a variable number of keys, and you want to sort them 'just in case', you're going to have a bad time in the long run.

P.S. Don't post your users' real data online ;)

Comment: thnx for all inputs. All this was test data.